# How return result from request, and after perform async task but without callback in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, mongoose

iOS application perform request for sending messages to users. I want to return result to application, and after that send push notification to users, and I don't want to wait until notifications were pushed successfully or not.

```
app.post("/message", function(req, res, next) {
    User.sendMessages(query, options, function(err, results) {
        res.json(results);
        sendPushNotifications();
    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're currently doing?

Comment: After res.json(results); application get response and others operations will perform? Let's imagine that sendPushNotifications() performing during a lot of time. Application get response before this operation completed?

Comment: Yes. That's how it works. Keep in mind everything that happens in node is in a single thread, unlike other back-end languages you might be used to. So requests, jobs, everything happens in that single thread. Unless of course you use cluster or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it works.

Keep in mind everything that happens in node is in a single thread, unlike other back-end languages you might be used to.

Requests, jobs, everything happens in that single thread. Unless, of course, you use cluster or something like that.